# Placing leaflet controls side-by-side instead of vertically stacked in R/Shiny with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, leaflet

What I want to do is pretty simple: I want my leaflet controls to be aligned side-by-side in rows rather than vertically as columns (as leaflet automatically does).

Here is some short example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%"), 
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays {width: 190px;}")))
  ), 

  server <- function(session, input, output){

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTerrain", group = "Layer1") %>% 
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Layer2") %>% 
        addLayersControl(position = "topleft", 
                         baseGroups = c("Layer1", "Layer2"), 
                         options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = F))
    })  # END RENDERLEAFET
  }  # END SERVER
)  # END SHINYAPP
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Both the zoom arrows and the layer box are leaflet layer controls. I want them to be side-by-side. I have altered the width of the layer box with HTML tags for that div class (in Shiny's UI call -- refer to code).

I opened the app in my web browser to inspect the source. Here's what I found: 
[image]

From what I can tell, both of the leaflet controls are in the class `.leaflet-top .leaflet-left` (makes sense, they're both in the top-left ;) ), but I can't figure out how to unstack them. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these this css rule

```
.leaflet-control-zoom.leaflet-bar.leaflet-control > a {
    float: right;
}
```

Switch between `right` and `left` depending on which side you want the plus and minus to be.

Comment: So this works for getting the + and - arrows side by side, but what I wanted was for the layer control box (with Layer1 and Layer2) to be beside the arrows. Following your example, I tried this: `.leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control-layers-expanded.leaflet-control > a{float: right;}`, which did not work. Any insight? What does the `> a` represent?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the CSS for the elements with the classes you have identified to display: inline-block and float: none.

display: inline-block does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit next to other elements.  [w3School reference for CSS Layout - display](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)
float:none the element does not float (will be displayed just where it occurs in the text).  [w3School reference for CSS Layout - Float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Try:

```
.leaflet-top .leaflet-left {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Nic3500. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.leaflet-control-layers { position: absolute; left: 86px }
```

or

```
.leaflet-control-zoom { position: absolute; left: 86px }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck