# Put two Leaflet controls next to each other but only two?

Tags: css, leaflet

I have three controls like this:

```
  map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
    position: "topright",
  });
  var searchControl = new L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
    position: "topright",
  }).addTo(map);
  var proximity = L.control({
    position: "topright",
  });
```

and I would like the latter two to appear next to each other. Applying [Placing leaflet controls side-by-side instead of vertically stacked in R/Shiny with HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42565497/308851) makes all three appear next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.leaflet-top.leaflet-right .leaflet-control:nth-child(2) {
    clear: none;
}
```